# Need output for an oracle query

Tags: sql, oracle, substr

I've a table and in that customer name column have some records. I need output as below

```
Table:
-------
Cname                     Cno
------                    ---
Ramesh babu                1
james k bold               2
Raghu manipati             3
uppu sukanya               4
```

Expected Output

```
cname:
------
babu
bold
manipati
sukanya
```

Comment: Have you used `INSTR`? check it ;).

Answer (score 0):

You need a combination of `SUBSTR()` and `INSTR()`.

Search for the position of space from last and extract all the characters after that.

`SUBSTR(CNAME , INSTR(CNAME,' ',-1) + 1)`

Answer (score 0):

Simple use **SUBSTR** and **INSTR**.

For example,

```
SQL> SELECT full_name,
  2    SUBSTR(full_name, instr(full_name, ' ', -1, 1) +1) last_name,
  3    id
  4  FROM t;

FULL_NAME      LAST_NAME              ID
-------------- -------------- ----------
Ramesh babu    babu                    1
james k bold   bold                    2
Raghu manipati manipati                3
uppu sukanya   sukanya                 4

SQL>
```